# POST from PHP to another (Java) web service and retrieving the (image) result

Tags: java, php, post, file-upload, http-headers

These are the steps:

- POST Form (file/image input) from the browser goes to a PHP server.
- The PHP server then use fsockopen to a Java (GlassFish/Jersey) REST service, sending the image as content for more advanced imaging work to be done there, and returning the resulting image back to the PHP server (or returning only a URI to the image).
- The PHP server then echos the result (img src= ..) back to the user in the HTML document.

Getting the image and all its attributes in the first step works great, but I need help setting up the headers correctly in the POST request from PHP to the web service.

Current code:

```
$fp = fsockopen("domain..", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
$contentlength = $_FILES["photo_file"]["size"];
$imageref = $_FILES["photo_file"]["tmp_name"];

$out = "POST /Uri to resource .. HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$out .= "Host: http://... \r\n";
$out .= "Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n";
$out .= "Content-type: multipart/mixed\r\n";
$out .= "Content-length: $contentlength\r\n\r\n";
$out .= "$imageref";

fwrite($fp, $out);
$theOutput;
while (!feof($fp))
{
  $theOutput .= fgets($fp, 128);
}
echo $theOutput;
fclose($fp);
```

Which echoes to the browser: "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Content-Type: text/html Content-Length: 717".

So I need better formed headers to get through to the REST web-method. And if I should achieve that does anyone know what paramaters to use in the jersey web-method to access the image?
For standard HTML forms its this:

```
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response getFullImage(@FormDataParam("photo_file") InputStream imageIS {..ImageIO.read(imageIS)..}
```

Would love suggestions to better architecture also for achieving this in HTML.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have problem with badly written request and should use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) at first place (in php), basic example usage (with writing to the file) from [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php):

```
$ch = curl_init("http://www.example.com/");
$fp = fopen("example_homepage.txt", "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Another example for setting post data from [`curl_setopt()` page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

```
$data = array('name' => 'Foo', 'file' => '@/home/user/test.png');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/upload.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

And handling HTTP status codes via [`curl_getinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php):

```
if(curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) === 200){
    ...
}
```

You also may set http headers manually:

```
curl_setopt($cURL,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array (
        "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8",
        "Expect: 100-continue"
    ));
```

Comment: Thanks. Trying CURL now and it seems I need to specify the headers, I'm getting "Unsupported Media Type" from the Java server. For images set content-type: multipart/mixed? Complete error msg: "The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method (Unsupported Media Type)". I need to know how to set up the paramater in the REST method also.

Comment: @gorn Add example with custom headers, you also may set custom request type with setting `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` (in `curl_setopt`).

Comment: Figured it out. First arrange a data array for CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data = array(   'uploaded_file' => '@'.$imagedata.';filename='.$filename,);    And then referene 'uploaded file' from a paramater in the jax-rs method like this: (@FormDataParam("uploaded_file") InputStream imageIS) { }        Sweet!  =)  Cheers!

Comment: One more issue, I just need the content from the jax-rs server response. I receive the response in PHP as a String with lots of header values, and the content/payload at the end of it. Any way I can get it to just return the payload text? Full response: HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0 JSP/2.2 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.1 Java/Oracle Corporation/1.7)
Server: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.1
Content-Type: text/plain
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 09 Feb 2012 23:46:05 GMT

URIIII

Comment: [Server response](http://pastebin.com/index/7BgSBBjU). I just want the content (plain text) as seen at the bottom. Any way PHP can filter out the headers? I thought of using string functions to get the last line, but that should not be necessary.

Comment: Are you using `CURLOPT_HEADER` in `curl_setop`? Set it to false. :) And you should be just fine. You can always use: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php

Comment: Oh wow, that was too easy! I'm embarrassed =]  Anyways, thanks alot for your help. It saved me alot of time  :)